# Are there any log files you can examine do determine why an unrooted Android device is rebooting repeatedly?

Tags: logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are log files located on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/941/where-are-log-files-located-on-android)

Yesterday evening I left wi-fi enabled overnight. This morning I found my Archos 101 **rebooting over and over again** (eating up the battery power very quickly).

I managed to shut it down, plugged in the power, rebooted and now it's running fine.

But of course I would like to know what caused this.

**Are there any log files I can examine to determine the cause ?**

My device is an unrooted Archos 101.

Last thing I installed was the Flash 10.2 player update and a quickpix update.

---

**UPDATE:**

- Although I searched for it before posting my question, I obviously didn't find the following question: [where are logfiles located](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/941/where-are-log-files-located-on-android), which is virtually the same (as pointed out by Matthew+. *I stand corrected.*
- **This question may be closed.**

Comment: Maybe not an exact dupe, but I think that should answer your question.