# How can you determine what programs you installed last?

Tags: applications, updates, installation

Following [my question about logs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/are-there-any-log-files-you-can-examine-do-determine-why-an-unrooted-android-devi) I wonder if there is a way **to determine the last updates and applications which have been installed**.

**Does Android keep a chronological list of installed programs and updates ?**

*I am running Froyo 2.2.1 if that should make a difference.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, **Android Market** shows the list of installed apps in chronological order. So the latest app you've installed should be on the top (first) of the list. The app that was installed before this - should be the second.

Comment: This is only so when you only have one device. And, although much more unlikely, you can install applications outside the market , or come to think of it, you could use f.i. Amazon market ( not we in Europe, but even so ).

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *This is a partial answer*.

---

Android keeps a note on when an app was last update or first installed.

Setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC, enable USB debugging in the device, connect the device into PC using USB cable, launch a shell on PC and enter:

```
adb shell dumpsys package | awk '{if(/pkg=Package/) {print $2} else if(/firstInstallTime/) {print $1" "$2} else if(/lastUpdateTime/) {print $1" "$2"\n"} }'  | tr -d '}'
```

`dumpsys package` gives detailed information about all the packages installed in the system. Each package *et al.* is listed with `firstInstallTime` or `lastUpdateTime`.

Your output would be like:

```
com.estrongs.android.pop
firstInstallTime=2015-07-04 15:49:50
lastUpdateTime=2015-07-04 15:49:50

com.google.android.syncadapters.bookmarks
firstInstallTime=2013-04-24 13:33:43
lastUpdateTime=2013-04-24 13:33:43

com.sika524.android.quickshortcut
firstInstallTime=2015-06-01 01:14:17
lastUpdateTime=2015-06-01 01:14:17

com.google.android.youtube
firstInstallTime=2013-04-24 13:33:47
lastUpdateTime=2015-06-26 18:29:27
```

After every blank line the first line is the package name of an app (e.g. `com.estrongs.android.pop`). Follow the bullet points at the bottom of the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122740/96277) to know how to get the app's title/label from package name.

As for sorting the time in descending/ascending order, I don't know anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

I use the App Brain app on my phone, https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&feature=search_result you can choose which order to show installed apps (name, date installed, size, storage location)

Answer (score 1):

OK you will probably tell me why do I bump an old thread, but this is still relevant and comes up in google.

I use application Nofitication History which acts as a kind of event log because it records all notifications. In cathegory com.android.packageinstaller you can see history of all system installations and updates.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree
[image]
[image]

You can also search by keywords like added, removed or updated